# Best approach to be notified when a preference value has been reached

Tags: android

I have a perference(EditTextPreference) that contains a value(integer), i want to trigger a notification when the value of this preference has been reached. What is the best approach to use? Service or Alarm? And can you please provide me some examples. I never used such structures.
An error on the point between `km.onPreferenceChange`

```
Syntax error on token ".", ; expected

settings.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                public boolean km.onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) to your `EditTextPreference` and simply check if the new value exceeds your *limit* value.

Comment: Yes, but this is used when just a preference has been changed. Me, i want to trigger a notification when the value of this preference has been changed. Is that possible ?

Comment: @androniennn: Yes, that's possible. Create your `Notification` when the value has been reached, which you detect by using a listener to your preference.

Comment: Okay, i'll test it and let you know. Thanks :).

Comment: Can you please provide me an example. I'm really stucked :\

Comment: Which part? Create a `Notification` is simple - you can just follow the developers' guide.

Comment: How can i implement OnPreferenceChangeListener to the code ? Its parameters is: preference(the pointed preference) and NewValue, what's this newvalue? This is what i want to do: i have a preference that has 8000 as value(example), i want to trigger a notification when this value(8000) has been reached.

Comment: Use `yourEditTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(yourPreferenceListener)`. Inside your `yourListener`, make a check - does the new value exceeds your limit? If so, create a `Notification`.

Comment: @androniennn: Do you know how to add listeners and such things to objects? You may have to research a bit in order to fully understand.

Comment: Yes, my problem is mainly solved, i adopted an other alternative. For now, i have another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060939/schedule-notification-not-triggered/7061094#7061094