# Schedule notification not triggered

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have an application that i want it to launch a notification every x days(predefined by user). For that I'm using this code:
Class extends broadcast receiver:

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Votre vidange approche";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);


        CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification";
        CharSequence contentText = "Vérifier votre kilométrage";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Acceuil.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        final int HELLO_ID = 1;

        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
     }

    }
```

And this function in the other class to launch this previous class:

```
public void repeating() {
        AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1800000, pi);

    }
```

I set it to launch every half hour the notification but i never had it.
What's going on with this code?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` means 'now' up to the millisecond, so there is a possibility that by  the time it gets a chance to run, the triggerAtTime will have passed (not sure how AlarmManager handles this case). Try delaying it a few seconds to see if it runs properly: `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10 * 1000`.

On another note, repeating alarms with large intervals (such as days) are unreliable: if you process is killed, or throws an exception, or the device is rebooted, then it's alarms will be cleared. One alternative (although not 100% bulletproof) would be to schedule each next alarm from the previous one and save the time it will run to shared preferences for example. Then each time your application starts, check if the next run time is valid (i.e., in the future), and if not schedule a new alarm.

Comment: There is many notes to take. Thanks for answer. For the second point i'm not understading it at 100%. It's hard to code it. no ? plus as i know AlarmManager always stays active despite the reboot of system. :\

Comment: Okay, but i'm not understading the "trick" :\. Can you write some sample simple code of your point of vue if you can.

Comment: 30 minutes passed and there is not inr notification. Strange :\

Comment: Are you sure your receiver is properly registered in AndroidManifest.xml? Does it fire when you send a broadcast manually (use `adb shell am broadcast`)? You can also use the `adb -d shell dumpsys alarm` command to check if your alarm is properly registered.

Comment: I used /*adb -d shell dumpsys alarm */ and im not finding the Alarm for my app. Surely a bad writed code. Please re-check my code. (i added the service in the AndroidManifest).

Comment: I am not sure you can use an explicit Intent with a broadcast receiver. Try using an explicit one for creating your PendingIntent: ` Intent i=new Intent("MY_ACTION")`. Then register this action in the receiver's intent filter. The alarm registration code seems OK, check if there are any warnings in logcat.

Comment: I'm not understanding your idea. where do i create `Intent i=new Intent("MY_ACTION")` ? in what class? brodcast receiver one ? And how do i register this action in the receiver's intent ! Sorry for that .